# Copying TIMESTAMP to DATETIME on MySQL with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime

I have these two classes

```
class Source {
    // mapped to TIMESTAMP
    @Version
    @Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT '2016-01-01'")
    Instant myInstant;
}

class Destination {
    // mapped to DATETIME
    @Basic(optional=true)
    Instant myInstant;
}
```

When using Hibernate, I assign

```
destination.myInstant = source.myInstant;
```

and then the stored value is smaller by one hour than the original - both according to the command line MySQL client and in Java. My current timezone is UTC+1, so the reason is obviously a timezone conversion.

There are a few places where this can be fixed, but I'm looking for the best practice. The server should work world-wide, so it should continue to use UTC internally, right?

Should I just change the column type to `TIMESTAMP`? Then, why does `Instant` by default map to `DATETIME`?

---

According to [this article](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/), `Instant` *does* map to `TIMESTAMP`, but in my case it did not. Why?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the SQL generated from Hibernate.

Comment: @RickJames There's nothing interesting there: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows the types like `timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2016-01-01 01:00:00.000` and `datetime`. The statements are just simple select and update, with no logic behind. The values didn't get logged. I'd post the log anyway, but I'd have to replace the real class and field names by those used in my question and that's not worth it as there's really nothing there.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  '%zone%';`

Comment: @RickJames `system_time_zone = UTC `, `time_zone = SYSTEM`.

Comment: But you said "My current timezone is UTC+1" -- where did that come from?

Comment: @RickJames Sorry, I was wrong. UTC+1 is the current timezone of Germany, but the server shows `Thu Mar  2 12:21:15 UTC 2017`. And `SELECT now()` also shows `12:21`, so I'm even more confused now.

Comment: Me, too.  Think of the datatypes this way.  A `DATETIME` is a picture of the clock on the wall -- and that clock is adjusted forward or backward twice a year.  Hence the `DATETIME` has anomalies.  `TIMESTAMP` is is a location-independent representation of the time.  However it is adjusted based on where the use is doing the `INSERT` or `SELECT`.  So you get the illusion of "local time".  But a `TIMESTAMP`, as stored, will not run backwards one a year.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to work with timezones and Java 8 I would recommend using ZonedDateTime or **OffsetTimeZone** (the latter being prefered when working with Hibernate). For older versions use Calendar.

- When you instance it should go by default with the timezone of your computer.
- Check if the database is timestamp with or without timezone.
- The default you set is also without timezone, and if it is "with timezone" it should automatically add the database's offset.

I hope some of this works. Here's how I did in one of my projects.

```
@Column(name = "registration_time")
private OffsetDateTime registrationTime;
[...]
subscriber.setRegistrationTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
```

Comment: I'm not completely happy with your answer, but this is not your fault. I'll have to investigate more what's actually going on (see my answer to Rick James).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5 & above, TIMESTAMP values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and converted back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. This occurs only for the TIMESTAMP data type but not for DATETIME. This is the reason you are seeing the difference while assigning a TIMESTAMP to DATETIME. So, having both the columns of same type should work. Hibernate by default maps InstantType to database TIMESTAMP type. Though you could use it for both TIMESTAMP and DATETIME in MYSQL, they are handled differently.